# Each Dictionary entry must have an associated key attribute

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, dictionary

I am programming w Windows 8.1 App using C# and the MVVM-Light Toolkit from GalaSoft.

All I have is the code below:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" xmlns:vm="using:Scedule.ViewModel" />

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resource Dictionaries/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>      
</Application.Resources>
```

The error "Each Dictionary entry must have an associated key attribute" occurs and only disappears when I either remove

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resource Dictionaries/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

or

```
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" xmlns:vm="using:Scedule.ViewModel" />
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem here is?

Comment: Maybe a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514137/errors-in-app-xaml-trying-to-use-mvvm-light-in-windows-phone-8-project

Comment: `when I either remove the visual tree up to or the` -> this sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: @M4TKD I have  already checked that post and that does not help me out. It is told to remove the MergedDictionary but that is exactly what I am trying to implement here.

Comment: @KingKing By that I meant removing everything inside the <ResourceDictionary></ResourceDictionary>. I don't know why that it is not being shown up there. I will fix that!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Note that `Application.Resources` requires an instance of `ResourceDictionary`, so you have to do something like this:

```
<Application.Resources>    
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" xmlns:vm="using:Scedule.ViewModel" />
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resource Dictionaries/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>      
</Application.Resources>
```

So it's not strange at all, it's also not a bug. If you want your `ResourceDictionary` to be treated as a resource, you of course have to provide some `Key` for it, however in this case you really want to assign an instance of `ResourceDictionary` to the `Application.Resources`

Comment: That works! And thanks for the explanation - that is th emost important part when getting things answered. Thank you very much :)

Comment: This kept giving me errors but worked after i restarted visual studio.

Comment: I'm stupid or blind but what is the difference here that made this work other than a swap of lines 2 and 3?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths the problem is not just swapping. Everything was explained fairly clearly in my answer (I think so). You can even put the `<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" xmlns:vm="using:Scedule.ViewModel" />` at the end (but still inside `<ResourceDictionary>`). The OP's code intends to define ***2 resources***, the first has Key of `Locator`, but the second is just an object of another `ResourceDictionary` (and this does not have any `Key` assigned - that's an error and cannot be resolved). In fact the OP would like to use `MergedDictionaries`, you can search to learn more about that.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths when using a `MergedDictionaries`, we need an explicit declaration of `ResourceDictionary` (instead of using the implicit one - which is created by the XAML parser behind the scene). So in this case we need to put ***any other resources*** inside that explicitly declared `ResourceDictionary`. As I said `Application.Resources` should be assigned to an instance of `ResourceDictionary`. However in XAML code, sometimes you see there are ***more than 1 element*** inside the `<Application.Resources>` - but in fact all will be put in an implicit instance of `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: The issue I had when I was comparing with a nonworking one is I didn't realise that all the statements in the Application.Resources actually needed to end up in dictionary if one was being merged in. I'm still getting back in WPF after a long time away.