# How to resolve "..dictionary entry must have associated key" error?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, resourcedictionary, app.xaml, viewmodellocator

I've added a namespace to my App.xaml file in order to resolve my ViewModelLocator.cs location in the project.Then referenced the ns from a ResourceDictionary. But I get two errros when I add these:

`..Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.`

`'ViewModelLocator' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.ViewModels;assembly=MongoDBApp'`

I've checked firstly that the namespace is correct for the location of the ViewModelLocator, which is: `namespace MongoDBApp.ViewModels`.

I also checked the syntax on the reference in the ResourceDictionary which seems correct. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181461/each-dictionary-entry-must-have-an-associated-key-attribute) didn't resolve the error and I've cleaned and rebuilt the solution a few times.

Can anyone advise on how to resolve this error?

The definition of the App.xml file is as follows, the ResourceDictionary is near the bottom of the file:

```
<Application x:Class="MongoDBApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Converters"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.ViewModels;assembly=MongoDBApp"
             xmlns:validators="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Validator"
             StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/Views/MainView.xaml"
             d1p1:Ignorable="d">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Grid Width="16"
                                  Height="16"
                                  Margin="3 0 0 0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                                <Ellipse Width="16"
                                         Height="16"
                                         Fill="Red" />
                                <Ellipse Width="3"
                                         Height="8"
                                         Margin="0 2 0 0"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                         Fill="White" />
                                <Ellipse Width="2"
                                         Height="2"
                                         Margin="0 0 0 2"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                         Fill="White" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                                    BorderThickness="2"
                                    CornerRadius="2">
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                            </Border>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="mainViewModelLocator" ></local:ViewModelLocator>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Brown.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Brown.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>     
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know whether it will help you, but in the past I did this. I created a user control class, deriving from UserControl and then in the constructor I set ViewModelLocator, then every UserControl I added would use my base UserControl (therefore they all get VML automatically). If this is something that you think could solve your problem, I can write some pseudo code to show how I do it.

Comment: Could you post some pseudo code to show that solution?

Comment: Is ViewModelLocator public? Have you compiled the assembly in which it is located? (designer tends to not notice things that aren't compiled yet)  Also when using Merged dictionaries, you can only do things inside the Merged dictionaries section but you have two children which may be causing error. Move the local:ViewModelLocator inside Merged dictionaries and see if error goes away. (It will be become part of implicit ResourceDictionary child that will then get merged in with other dictionary declarations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, please note my ViewModelLocator in this case comes from prism (this is why I need IView, you don't if you use something else).

Base class

```
public class MyFormUserControl : UserControl, IView
{
    public MyFormUserControl()
    {
        if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            SetValue(ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModelProperty, true);
        }
    }
 }
```

UserControl

```
<controls:MyFormUserControl  x:Class="MyWpf1.UserControl1"
                         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                         xmlns:controls="path to the base class">

your usual xaml goes here

</controls:MyFormUserControl>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class UserControl1: MyFormUserControl
{
    public CrateFormView() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```